# Azure Stream Analytics Unique EventId Property is NULL

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm looking to assign a unique Id to each event that is processed via Azure Stream Analytics (IoT Hub input source).

It appears there is no way to just assign a new random Guid in ASA (like in SQL) but I did come across the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getmetadatapropertyvalue?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#unique-eventid-property) MSDN article which mentions being able to use the **GetMetadataPropertyValue** function to achieve what I want with the **EventId** property:

> Creates a unique id (Guid) for an input event, which can be useful for
>   primary key purposes. It is consistent (not random) i.e., Stream
>   Analytics will produce the same id for an event, if you go back in
>   time and re-read the same input event.

The issue I have is this function returns NULL each time when I try it in the query builder. Am I missing something or is there another way to achieve a Unique Id for an event?

Comment: I believe the example there is only valid for EventHub inputs. For IoT Hub inputs there is no property named "EventId". GetMetadataProperty will only read fields which are in the message - and not generate any new values. Instead you could maybe use a custom JavaScript function to create an unique Id, for instance by hashing certain fields from your message

Comment: @silent I have tested with an EventHub input, it is also invalid. I downloaded the sample data, there is no EventId property in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this property doesn't work when you test it from sample data (we need some additional metadata). 
However you should get the GUID value when you run the job on live data from Event Hub or IoT Hub.

Let me know if it works for you! Sorry for the inconvenience.

JS

Comment: Yes,It works. I have verified with IoT Hub as an input and Azure Function as output.

Comment: Thanks this is good to know. The original plan was to use Azure Table Storage but we are now going to use Azure SQL and let the DB assign the GUID. Thanks for the info!