# Generating unique identifier from Azure Stream Analytics Job

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to use `Azure Stream Analytics Job` for writing data to `SQL Server`. I use unique identifier for `Id` column, however it seems that I can not generate a guid from `Azure Stream Analytics Job`. How can I generate it? Should I change my id column type? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `GetMetadataPropertyValue` function.

> The EventId property creates a unique ID (Guid) for an input event,
> which can be useful for primary key purposes. EventId is consistent
> (not random); if you go back in time and re-read the same input event,
> Stream Analytics will produce the same ID.

Here is the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/getmetadatapropertyvalue?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#unique-eventid-property). You can also refer to [Azure Stream Analytics Unique EventId Property is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396858/azure-stream-analytics-unique-eventid-property-is-null/49421164#49421164).